# Realm: Iterating a RealmObject and clearing an ArrayList field

Tags: java, android, iterator, realm

I have a `RealmResults<Section>` that has a `RealmList<Event>` field that I want to clear on each Section.

I've tried (insude mRealm.executeTransaction)

```
for (Section section : mSections) {
    section.getEvents().clear();
}
```

and

```
Iterator<Section> sectionIterator = mSections.iterator();
while (sectionIterator.hasNext()) {
    sectionIterator.next().getEvents().clear();
}
```

but Realm throws this exception

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: No outside
>   changes to a Realm is allowed while iterating a RealmResults. Use
>   iterators methods instead.

Comment: What is returned by `getEvents()`?  Another `ArrayList`?

Comment: The Events object is a `RealmList<Event>`, which is pretty much an ArrayList

Comment: Have you tried just using a traditional for loop?  This might work since you're not actually removing the items that you are iterating over.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that before! It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are not actually removing elements that you are iterating over, you can just use a traditional for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mSections.size(); i++) {
    mSections.get(i).getEvents().clear();
}
```

Note that if you did need to remove elements using an `Iterator`, you would need to use the `remove()` method on the `Iterator` itself.

[See Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Iterator.html)